# How to migrate data from one version of an app to another when the signing key is changed?

Tags: android

We have an existing app that is signed using a signing key that was generated using a signing key with an expiry of something like 10 years. Previously all of our clients had installed this app via side-loading so it hadn't been a problem. Now we want to put the app onto the play store - this is impossible with the app that is currently in use because the expiry date is too short.

It seems that we have to make a new version of the app that is signed with a new key with a longer expiry. Is there a way to make it so that the data in the old app can be shared with the data in the new app so that it can be more of a seamless transition?

Comment: Sure. Update your app to sync all the settings to save to a server, then sync them back to the new app.

Comment: Thanks, we already have a syncing architecture. What I'm wanting to know is if there is some way to enable the data to be shared without requiring a sync.

Comment: There are a lot of ways.  You might want to be more specific about what exactly you're trying to share.

Comment: try use contentproviders to get data from old app..

Comment: The most important files would be sqlite databases, but we also have other files generated by the user such as images that would need to be shared as well.